# Use of case keyword in Apache Spark Coding

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In many samples of Apache Spark code we can the below code

```
val input = sc.hadoopFile[Text, Text, KeyValueTextInputFormat](inputFile).map{
   case (x, y) => (x.toString, y.toString)
}
```

Can someone please explain the use of `case (x,y)` here? I am aware of the use of case statement for class creation and pattern matching. However I am unable to understand the user of `case (x,y` in map function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a form of function literals using pattern-matching. You could also write `map { i => i match { case (x, y) => (x.toString, y.toString) } }`. See [Programming in Scala, "`case` sequences as partial functions"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284#v=onepage&q&f=false).